# Array of lists in R - Convert them to Origin

Tags: r, arrays, list

In R, i have an array of lists called "test [[]]", where the lists present the data like this:

```
X44231 X44232 X44233 X44234 X44235 X44236 X44237 X44238
1     100      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
2       0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
3       0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
4     100      0      0      0      0      0    200      0
5       0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
6     700    900      0      0   1100   1200   1200   1200
7       0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
8       0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
9       0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
10      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
11      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
12      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
13      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
14      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
15      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
```

Some columns are named with X and a number, and I need to convert them to origin = "1899-12-30", but I don't know how to apply this rule to a column title and still take the X out of the way (note: no are all the columns that I have to apply this conversion)

Conversion example:

```
as.Date(44228, origin = "1899-12-30")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this is what you're looking for

```r
library(tidyverse)

read.table(text = "X44231 X44232 X44233 X44234 X44235 X44236 X44237 X44238
1     100      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
2       0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
3       0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
4     100      0      0      0      0      0    200      0
5       0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
6     700    900      0      0   1100   1200   1200   1200
7       0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
8       0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
9       0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
10      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
11      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
12      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
13      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
14      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
15      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0", header = T) ->df
   
names(df) %>% 
   str_remove("X") %>% 
   as.numeric() %>% 
   as.Date(origin = "1899-12-30") -> c_names

names(df) <- c_names
df
#>    2021-02-04 2021-02-05 2021-02-06 2021-02-07 2021-02-08 2021-02-09 2021-02-10
#> 1         100          0          0          0          0          0          0
#> 2           0          0          0          0          0          0          0
#> 3           0          0          0          0          0          0          0
#> 4         100          0          0          0          0          0        200
#> 5           0          0          0          0          0          0          0
#> 6         700        900          0          0       1100       1200       1200
#> 7           0          0          0          0          0          0          0
#> 8           0          0          0          0          0          0          0
#> 9           0          0          0          0          0          0          0
#> 10          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
#> 11          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
#> 12          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
#> 13          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
#> 14          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
#> 15          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
#>    2021-02-11
#> 1           0
#> 2           0
#> 3           0
#> 4           0
#> 5           0
#> 6        1200
#> 7           0
#> 8           0
#> 9           0
#> 10          0
#> 11          0
#> 12          0
#> 13          0
#> 14          0
#> 15          0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that tries to handle the cases where the column names are not in the form `"Xnnnn"`, with `n` decimal digits.

```
convertDate <- function(x){
  y <- sub("^X", "", x)
  d <- as.Date(as.integer(y), origin = "1899-12-30")
  na <- is.na(d)
  d[na] <- x[na]
  d
}

convertDate(x)
#[1] "2021-02-04" "2021-02-05" "2021-02-06" "2021-02-07"
#[5] "2021-02-08" "2021-02-09" "2021-02-10" "2021-02-11"
```

To change the column names, assign the return value of this function to `names(test)` or to `colnames(test)`.

```
names(test) <- convertDate(names(test))
```

**Data**

```
x <- scan(what = character(),
          text = "X44231 X44232 X44233 X44234 X44235 X44236 X44237 X44238")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to base R:

```
#reproducible example
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(100,0,0,100),2))
colnames(df) <- c("X44231", "X44232")

#actual code
colnames(df) <- as.Date(as.numeric(gsub("X","",colnames(df))), origin = "1899-12-30")
df
```

yields

```
  2021-02-04 2021-02-05
1        100          0
2          0        100
```